# Rails model not valid, but <span class='error'> missing in the resulting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, error-handling

So, I have a create form and I purposely fill in wrong values so the resulting object is invalid. Everything is standard rails, so when posting to the `create` action, the `save` method fails. I render `index` again with the faulty object (the form is on the index page).

So far so good, I byebug the form and indeed: The object has errors:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fb4aa50c9e8 @base=#<ViewReport id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, from_date: "2015-08-16 22:00:00", to_date: "2015-08-16 22:00:00", name: "">, @messages={:name=>["mag niet leeg zijn"], :from_date=>["'From date' moet eerder zijn dan 'to_date'!"]}>
```

And I even have the `field_for_errors` rendered by rails:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="view_report_name">Name</label></div>
  <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="view_report_name" name="view_report[name]" type="text" value="" /></div>
</div>
```

What's lacking, though, is the `<span class='error'>Error message here</span>` element!

I really want my span. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As requested, the controller code:

```
  def create
    @view_report = ViewReport.new params[:view_report]
    if @view_report.save
      redirect_to :index
    else
      @view_reports = ViewReport.find_each
      render :index
    end
  end
```

And the form:

```
  <h2>New View Report</h2>
  <%= form_for @view_report, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :from_date %>
      <%= f.date_select :from_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :to_date %>
      <%= f.date_select :to_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

PS: I need to re-instantiate @view_reports in the create action, for it is used in the index view

Comment: Add your controller code please.

Comment: And add the form view code.

Comment: Well where is the error template inside the view?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: No need for that. I want the errors to be displayed inline of the form

Comment: @Stobbej It is needed to.. I am not playing here with you.. trying to help. How would you print the error, if you don't show by which means you are trying to _print_.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I know you're trying to help and appreciate that very much. I have what you suggest. But this gives me a list of errors _above_ the form. I want them _inline_ the form. All the other forms in my app work as I'd expect (inline errors). But this one doesn't, and it frustrates me why this happens in this particular instance.

Comment: @Stobbej Can you add the partial inside the form and the content of the partial also.. So that  I can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

After form_for, you'll need something like this

```
<% if @view_report.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @view_report.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Go ahead and add the classes and html you would prefer.  I will sometimes separate the errors into another shared/view that I can call for any form so it's only in one place.  Depends on the unique needs of the form.

BTW - you shouldn't need this:  `, url: {action: "create"}` if your @view_report is a new_record (no id yet).  It will know to post to the correct action.

Comment: Yes this is what one way to print. @stobbej see now why I asked to show you.

Comment: @stobbej, another way, I wouldn't make my answer. But telling, the same can be done using the Rails `flash` view helper method.( read from online source, how to do it)

Comment: @Swards and ArupRakshit, thanks guys, I have this, and this works. But this gives me the errors in a list. Not inline the form. For all the other forms I have, rails automatically adds the desired span to the form. I just don't get why it not the case in this particular instance of a form.

Comment: @Stobbej Are you using CSS/JS to do it inline ? may be then some ID/class issue, you are missing.

Comment: You can access errors per field by `@view_report.errors[:attribute]` and make the change to the html depending on the result.

Answer (score 0):

I made the wrong assumption, my bad. The assumption was that Rails would set inline errors in the form when the object was invalid. The inline errors that appeared 'automatically' inline in my previous forms came in fact from [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)!